# Rhotic accent in London or in the rest of the UK?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

Good evening or good afternoon for the American.

I read and it is known that most British accents are non-rhotic, but I’m now in London and I have the feeling that the Rs after vowels and before a consonant or at the end of the word are slightly pronounced. Can anybody explain it to me ?
Thanks

Comment: When I (an American) am in England and am exposed to British accents regularly, I start hearing /r/s in words where I know they're not really there, even words like *dawn* that should never have /r/s. It you're used to listening to rhotic accents, are you sure that it's not your brain playing tricks on you? (And Londoners ***do*** pronounce them at the end of a word if the next word starts with a vowel.)

Comment: As a Londoner myself, I am always puzzled by Americans claiming that we "don't pronounce" the Rs. In fact we do pronounce them: but we just don't over-exaggerate them as rhotic accents do. If a words ends in "er", we will pronounce it "er"... as opposed to rhotic speakers who, to our ears, actually drop the "e"! For example the word "letter": we prounounce "er" at the end. But Americans sound like they're saying "leddrrr"! It's all about perception.

Comment: As a Londoner who has also lived in Bristol, the London pronunciation of 'er' is more like 'ah' (or maybe 'uh'; time for some IPA, maybe). The 'r' may determine the pronunciation of the final vowel but is not pronounced anything like an 'r' between two vowels, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Rhotic accents do exist in England. West Country English (think stereotypical *yarr* pirates for an approxiation) is typically rhotic, but that's probably not what you're thinking of.

You might be thinking of the [intrusive or linking R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R), which is common in most dialects of English English. An /r/ sound is inserted between two vowels.

The sentence "I saw a llama and an alpaca" is often pronounced something like "I saw *ra llama *rand an alpaca".